# how to use Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I am sending around 3000 email with attachment. For this reason I am using swift mailers AntiFlood and Throttler plugin. But I am getting following error:

Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\swiftmailer\Mailer::plugins'

Here is my main-local.php where I have added plugins.

```
        'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
                            'class'         => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                            'host'          => 'mail.test.com',
                            'username'      => 'noreply@test.com',
                            'password'      => 'welcome@123',
                            'port'          => '25',
                            //'encryption'    => 'tls',
                        ],
        'plugins'=> [
                        [
                            'class' => 'Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin',
                            'constructArgs' => ['20'],
                        ],
                        [
                             'class' => 'Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin',
                             'constructArgs' => [30,45],
                        ],
                    ],
    ],
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html) the `plugins` key should be inside `transport`:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
        'class'         => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host'          => 'mail.test.com',
        'username'      => 'noreply@test.com',
        'password'      => 'welcome@123',
        'port'          => '25',
        'plugins'=> [
            [
                'class' => 'Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin',
                'constructArgs' => ['20'],
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin',
                'constructArgs' => [30,45],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```